# Cloudformation Health Check "Invalid Request"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to deploy this Cloudwatch Alarm and Health Check using Cloudformation, and I'm getting an error that the request is invalid for the Health Check, and can't understand why. Hoping someone could help me figure out the problem.

```
  rEventBusCwAlarm:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties:
      ActionsEnabled: FALSE
      AlarmDescription: Alarm that monitors the health of event busses in current region by counting Failed Invocations
      ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanThreshold
      EvaluationPeriods: 5
      MetricName: FailedInvocations
      Namespace: AWS/Events
      Threshold: 10
      Statistic: Sum
      Period: 10


  rEventBusHealthCheck:
    Type: AWS::Route53::HealthCheck
    Properties:
      HealthCheckConfig:
        Type: CLOUDWATCH_METRIC
        InsufficientDataHealthStatus: Healthy
        AlarmIdentifier:
            Name: !Ref rEventBusCwAlarm
            Region: !Sub ${pRegion}
```

This is the exact error I get:

```
Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: AWS::Route53::HealthCheck" (RequestToken: 281f0512-ba1d-3c44-4c44-d371f07fae81, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

Comment: Can you show the error?

Comment: @jordanm Added it to the post.

Comment: Cloudformation errors typically suck. Check the structure of HealthCheckConfig in the docs - your probably missing a required parameter like `FullyQualifiedDomainName` -  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_HealthCheckConfig.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the alarm, rather than the health check. If you try to create this alarm NOT via Cloudformation you will get:

`Only a period greater than 60s is supported for metrics in the "AWS/" namespaces`

So change

`Period: 10`

to

`Period: 60` (or more)

It looks like a Cloudformation bug, you should not be able to create that alarm.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay in replying. That was indeed the issue, but I had found it another way and forgot to check back here. Thank you!